# Error 500 on heroku, req.body returned undefined

Tags: heroku

```js
import express from 'express'
const router = express.Router()

import { protect, admin } from '../middleware/index.js'

import {
  registerUser,
  ActivateUser,
  loginUser,
  getUsers,
  deleteAccount,
  adminDeleteAccount,
  forgotPassword,
  resetPassword,
  updateUserProfile,
  getUserbyId,
  createUserByAdmin,
  getUserByAdmin,
  updateUserByAdmin,
} from '../Controllers/userControllers.js'

router.get('/', protect, admin, getUsers)

router.post('/admin', protect, admin, createUserByAdmin)

router.post('/register', registerUser)

router.post('/activate', ActivateUser)

router.post('/login', loginUser)

router.post('/forgotpassword', forgotPassword)

router.put('/profile', protect, updateUserProfile)

router.get('/:id', protect, getUserbyId)

router.get('/admin/:id', protect, admin, getUserByAdmin)

router.put('/resetpassword/:id/:token', resetPassword)

router.put('/admin/:id', protect, admin, updateUserByAdmin)

router.delete('/delete/:id', protect, deleteAccount)

router.delete('/admin/delete', protect, admin, adminDeleteAccount)

export default router
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO99p.jpg)

I hosted a full stack MERN project on heroku but it keeps returning error 500 as seen in the picture attached, 'cannot destructure email as it is undefined. The interesting part is that the app works fine in development! ANy help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: There isn't enough context shown there. Please [edit] your question and paste the _entire_ set of errors into it as a code block.